# Increasing Sequence of Rationals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x$ be any real number. Construct a sequence $x_n$ of rational numbers such that 
$$x = \sup\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}.$$
I was trying $x_n = [ 10^n x ]/10^n$, but is it actually monotone increasing?
If so, how to prove it analytically?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to read about [Continued Fractions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

Comment: In your first sentence, there is no requirement that the sequence be monotone increasing.  Is that a requirement, and if so, does it have to be strictly increasing?  Did you mean the square brackets to be the floor function?

Comment: Yes,it is a requirement and I ment the greatest integer function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your sequence $$x_n = \dfrac{\lfloor 10^n x \rfloor}{10^n}$$ will do the job. Your sequence is also monotone increasing.

**HINT**:

To prove monotone increasing, try to prove the following first:
$$a \lfloor x \rfloor \leq \lfloor ax \rfloor$$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your sequence is easy justify

$\left|\frac{\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor}{10^n}-x\right|=\left|\frac{\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor-10^nx}{10^n}\right|=\frac{\text{fractional part of }10^nx}{10^n}\le\frac1{10^n}$

You see from here that the convergence is exponential, which very rapid!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  First show that $\lfloor x \rfloor \le \frac{ \lfloor a \cdot x \rfloor }{a}$.  Then it should be clear that $x_{n+1} \ge x_n$ when $a = 10$.  (This is essentially the same as @Marvis' answer.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind help.Wasn't there another answer that does not use my example?

Comment: To be a smart-ass, one might say that the sequence $x_n$ is provided by the _definition_ of $x$ as a Dedekind cut or Cauchy sequence.  QED (almost).

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, your sequence is monotone, but not necessarily strictly increasing.  For example, if $x = 0$ all $x_n = 0$.  If you want it strictly increasing, you might try
$x_n = \dfrac{[10^n x] - 1}{10^n}$.